# storing single values from an arraylist into an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I want to get values from an arraylist so that I can graph them but I am having trouble getting them into an array. In this loop, I am looping over my sorted hashmap and attempting to store values in an array(doesn't work).

```
long v [] = null;

for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
{
       v = entry.getValue().singleValues;
}
```

This is my NumberHolder class

```
private static class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurrences = 0;
    public int sumtime_in_milliseconds = 0; 
    public ArrayList<Long> singleValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

I eventually want an array filled with single values so that I can graph it.

EDIT

This is what I have now, and  Eclipse gives me this never ending error suggestions of converting my array to `Object[]` which gives me problems when using `dataset.addSeries` for my graph.

```
for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
{ 
   graphMaker(entry.getValue().occurrences,entry.getValue().singleValues.toArray());
}                                        


public static void graphMaker(int totalValues, Object[] objects)
{

    int bin = 1000;
    HistogramDataset dataset = new HistogramDataset();
    dataset.setType(HistogramType.RELATIVE_FREQUENCY);
    dataset.addSeries("Histogram",objects,bin, 0, 120000);
```

Comment: You'll have to initialize `v` first to anything besides null in order to use that

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign an ArrayList to an Array like that. Maybe you could use the [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method:

```
long v [] = null;

for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
{
   v = entry.getValue().singleValues.toArray(new long[0]);
}
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to use 'long' and not 'Long' ? Because the difference here can save you a for loop or utility call. If you don't need to use a primitive then don't.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
final ArrayList<Long> t = entry.getValue().singleValues;
v = new long[t.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) v[i] = t.get[i];
```

Edit: fixed handling of primitive type

Comment: for both of these, I am getting `The method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (long[])` and then when I take out the arguments it says `The method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (long[])` and suggest converting v to Object []

Answer (score 0):

```
v = entry.getValue().singleValues.toArray(new long[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly because `long` is not equal to `Long`.

You can use the [Apache Commons Lang Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). There is a class called `ArrayUtils` that have a function called [toPrimitive](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Long%5B%5D,%20long%29).

If you use that function you can do:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
{
   v = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(entry.getValue().singleValues.toArray(new Long[0]));
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use the library, you can do the following:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
{
   v = new long[entry.getValue().singleValues.size()];
   for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
       v[i]=entry.getValue().singleValues.get(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Question for the poster: Do you NEED primitive 'long'? If not, Change your data type. Problem solved as others have described

Comment: Change it to what? I think I would need to change my arraylist too

Comment: What I understand on Christian comment is to change `long v[]` to `Long v[]`, not the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Set<Long> values = new HashSet<Long>();
Iterator<NumberHolder> it = entries.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    NumberHolder numberHolder = it.next();
    values.addAll(numberHolder.singleValues;
}
Long[] v1 = values.toArray();
// transform to primitive long array
long[] v = new long[v1.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
    v[i] = v1[i];
}
```